# Unable to connect to ssh server using system() function in C++

Tags: c++, ssh, client, system

I'm trying to connect to my school's ssh server using a simple C++ program that I wrote. My windows computer has OpenSSH Client installed and I'm able to establish a connection using the command prompt.

Here's how it works via the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Username>ssh username@example.server.name
Password:
Last login: Sat Sep  5 15:20:44 2020 from 117.194.240.211

username@example:~$
```

I was hoping to replicate this action with a simple C++ program I wrote. Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string hostIP;
    string username;
    string password;

    cout << "Welcome to SSH Program" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------" << endl;

    cout << "\nEnter host ip or name: ";
    cin >> hostIP;

    cout << "Enter username: ";
    cin >> username;

    cout << "\nConnecting...\n" << endl;

    string composite = "ssh " + username + "@" + hostIP;

    char command[100];
    strcpy_s(command, composite.c_str());

    system(command);

    system("pause");
}
```

Unfortunately when I attempt to run this program I get the following output:

```
Welcome to SSH Program
----------------------

Enter host ip or name: example.server.name
Enter username: username

Connecting...

'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As far as I understand, this message is only supposed to come if OpenSSH Client isn't installed on my system. But it is as evidenced in the command prompt example.

Why is this happening and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Does your `PATH` variable contain a path to where `ssh` is stored on your computer? Can you run it from the console manually? You maybe can fix it using tje full path of where `ssh` was installed.

Comment: Only explanation is that the *environment* in which you are running your program is different from the environment in which you are running your command prompt. Specifically the PATH variable must be different.

Comment: You can get the PATH variable from the command prompt just by typing `PATH`. You can get the PATH variable from your program with `#include <cstdlib>` and `cout << getenv("PATH") << '\n';`

Comment: I think this is the main problem from what you all have commented. When I typed "path" into the command prompt, there's C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ present. I assume this means OpenSSH is installed. How do I make sure Visual Studio (the IDE I'm using to compile) follows this as well?

Comment: @MauriceKasomwung IIRC Project/Properties/Debugging/Environment. I think this applies even when launching your program without debugging.

Comment: Typing "path" to the command propt will never output what you claim, unless there's small cmdlet installed. You should be able to use `system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe")` that shoul work as mentioned though.

Comment: Try restarting your IDE.

Comment: I've managed to make it work by changing the platform to (All Platforms). previously it was x86. Can anyone tell me why this caused the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who commented and helped on this question. Turned out it was an issue of the platform I was building my program for. The platform was initially set to x86 but once I changed it to x64, everything worked as intended.