# How to run SSH with system() in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ssh

I've written a simple program to connect to a Linux server using SSH via my C++ program. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string hostIP;
    string username;
    string password;

    cout << "Welcome to SSH Program" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------" << endl;

    cout << "\nEnter host ip or name Example: \"capa.its.uow.edu.au\": ";
    cin >> hostIP;

    cout << "Enter username: ";
    cin >> username;

    cout << "\nConnecting...\n" << endl;

    string composite = "ssh " + username + "@" + hostIP;

    char command[100];
    strcpy(command, composite.c_str());

    system(command);

    system("pause");
}
```

It runs well on Ubuntu, but when I compile this same code on Visual Studio in Windows and execute it, the console present me with this error: `'ssh.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

This didn't make sense to me because OpenSSH Client is clearly installed on my computer and I'm able to establish an SSH connection if I directly enter `ssh username@server.ip.address` in the command prompt.

I thought it might be an issue with the environment paths and so in Visual Studio, I checked `Project>Properties>VC++ Directories>Executable Directories`. There I found `C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\` among other paths, located in the `Evaluated value:` box.

Doesn't this mean everything should run fine since the OpenSSH directory is located in the path? Also, like I said, I am able to connect via SSH if I enter the command directly into the command prompt instead of the program.

Please help. I've been really scratching my head over this since last night.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to connect to ssh server using system() function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63750761/unable-to-connect-to-ssh-server-using-system-function-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue. It seems to have been a problem with the selected platform in Visual Studio. Initially the platform for the project was set for an x86 architecture. This is the reason why ssh.exe could not be accessed even though it was present in the environment path.

By changing the platform to 64-bit architecture in the project properties, the program could reference the correct environment variables and execute ssh.exe as intended.